# Use flex to get all the rows the same height in different columns?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to make a product item page where you can view 3 items in a row and where every detail starts on the same height.

It also must be responsive so on a mobile you get item 1, 2 and 3 among each other.

[image: Text]

How can I make image 1,2 and 3 on one line so they are all at the same height of image 2?

```css
.flexbox {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #565656;
  padding: 5px;
  align-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flexbox div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin: 5px;
}

.flexbox .left {
  background-color: #D30058;
}

.flexbox .center {
  background-color: #36ABE1;
}

.flexbox .right {
  background-color: #23B776;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
  .flexbox {
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
  }
  .flexbox div {
    width: 33.33% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="left">
    <span class="title">
      <p>Title 1</p>
    </span>
    <span class="subtitle">
      <p>Sub title 1 (short)</p>
    </span>
    <span class="image">
      <p>Image 1</p>
    </span>
    <span class="price">
      <p>Price 1</p>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <span class="title">
      <p>Title 2</p>
    </span>
    <span class="subtitle">
      <p>Sub title 2<br /> (This could be a very long title, maybe over two or three lines)</p>
    </span>
    <span class="image">
      <p>Image 2</p>
    </span>
    <span class="price">
      <p>Price 2</p>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span class="title">
      <p>Title 3</p>
    </span>
    <span class="subtitle">
      <p>Sub title 3 (short)</p>
    </span>
    <span class="image">
      <p>Image 3</p>
    </span>
    <span class="price">
      <p>Price 3</p>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you're asking for can't be done 100% with current setup those elements don't know anything about each other so why should they be aligned evenly relative to each other ? or much more accurate **How ?**, Using flexbox you have to define a height on an outer parent and `overflow:auto` to manage long elements  https://jsfiddle.net/dpkzw0cr/ Using CSS grid this can be done easily still a change in html is a must https://jsfiddle.net/dpkzw0cr/1/ Because [Subgrid](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid-2/) is yet to be implemented

Comment: Using CSS grid could also be a good solution, only this doesn't give the right view on a mobile so I think I go for the flexbox solution. Or can it be done with CSS grid so I all the colored items together?

Comment: I have been looking to the flexbox solution, is it possible to get a fixed height for eg. the Title? Now each row will take up about 75px (300/4) but I want my title to have max 40px height.

Comment: You can do anything you want with height/width https://jsfiddle.net/tubkywpa/ i removed media for the purpose of illustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Make your .flexbox div -> flex as well.

```
.flexbox div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
```

```css
.flexbox {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #565656;
  padding: 5px;
  align-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flexbox div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin: 5px;
}

.flexbox .left {
  background-color: #D30058;
}

.flexbox .center {
  background-color: #36ABE1;
}

.flexbox .right {
  background-color: #23B776;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
  .flexbox {
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
  }
  .flexbox div {
    width: 33.33% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="left">
    <span class="title">
      <p>Title 1</p>
    </span>
    <span class="subtitle">
      <p>Sub title 1 (short)</p>
    </span>
    <span class="image">
      <p>Image 1</p>
    </span>
    <span class="price">
      <p>Price 1</p>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <span class="title">
      <p>Title 2</p>
    </span>
    <span class="subtitle">
      <p>Sub title 2<br /> (This could be a very long title, maybe over two or three lines)</p>
    </span>
    <span class="image">
      <p>Image 2</p>
    </span>
    <span class="price">
      <p>Price 2</p>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span class="title">
      <p>Title 3</p>
    </span>
    <span class="subtitle">
      <p>Sub title 3 (short)</p>
    </span>
    <span class="image">
      <p>Image 3</p>
    </span>
    <span class="price">
      <p>Price 3</p>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still not 100% accurate if you add borders you can see it https://jsfiddle.net/tpcwu281/

Comment: then give each element certain height.